# Guardar informação de um vetor a cada chamada da função

Tags: javascript, json, array, lógica

tenho uma função no meu código javascript, nesta função é preenchido informações numa variável que será adicionado na posição de um vetor, vou tentar ilustrar com partes em pseudocódigo o exemplo:

```
funcao(){
   a = scan;
   vetor.push(a);
   //codigo do json:
   var sessaoResposta = {"respostas": vetor};
   mySessions.push(sessaoResposta);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(mySessions));
}
```

O problema é que o resultado final no console sempre será o array completo com os mesmos dados (que é o dado final), toda passada da função ele lerá o vetor com todos os scanners já coletados e assim atualizando os valores anteriores.
Ou seja, se uma vez o vetor foi ["oi"] e depois passou a ser ["oi","ola"], o resultado final de todas as 'sessaoResposta' que eu empurrei pro vetor 'mySessions' será o último valor do vetor : [["oi","ola"] ,["oi","ola"]], perdendo assim o estado do vetor quando era só ["oi"].
O resultado desejado pra isso seria: [["oi"] ,["oi","ola"]]

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque você está usando sempre a mesma referência de `vetor` que é *global*.
Você pode resolver isso criando um vetor de *escopo local* da tua função.

```
function funcao(){
   a = scan;
   vetor.push(a);
   let novoVetor = [].concat(vetor);

   //codigo do json:
   var sessaoResposta = {"respostas": novoVetor};
   mySessions.push(sessaoResposta);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(mySessions));
}
```

Aqui o link do [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zpphpxL/4/) para exemplificar.

Comment: vi também que com  a função 'slice()' é possível salvar por cópia

Comment: @Dr.G, quase todas as funções de array em javascript retornam um novo array como resultado. A função do `splice()` não seria exatamente para esse caso, mas se atendeu o teu propósito, não podemos dizer que está mais certo ou mais errado. Sugiro dar uma olhada neste [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), é bem útil.